# Integer types with defined width

Tags: c, types, integer, c99

I am reading *C in a Nuttshell* came across a topic 
**Integer types with exact width (C99)**
[image]

Can somebody please explain me what is the use of this data-types

Where can i use this data-types in code

Why this data-types have been introduced

I am a beginner in C programming

Comment: Try to ask _"what's the size of `int`?"_ in a portable way and you'll see that you will answer _"I don't know"_. With these types you exactly specify the size (or the minimum required size or...) It makes your code clear and portable (to begin with)

Comment: I would suggest to read on...

Comment: @CannedMoose thanks but the explanation is not given i read further .Another topic starts after this topic

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thanks but can you please explain what you are trying to say

Comment: What _exactly_ do you not understand un the explanation provided? It's pretty clear, for example `uint8_t` is an 8 bit unsigned integer. Please [edit]  your question and clarify.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks please help what should i edit in my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C is now a rather old language (since the early 1970s) and compatibility has always be a concern. In those old times, size of integers could be different on different architectures. As a result `sizeof(int)` is still an implementation detail. What is required by standard:

- `char` is the smallest memory unit and has at least 8 bits - all other types have a size that is a multiple of the size of `char`
- `short` has at least 16 bits
- `int` is at least as large as `short` and has at least 16 bits
- `long` is at least as large as `int` and has as least 32 bits
- `long long` is at least as large as `long` and has as least 64 bits

But for example, you cannot know what is the most appropriate type to process 32 bits values. That's the reason why *integer types with exact (or minimal) width* were invented.

For portability reasons, C language make no assumption on the underlying machine, that's the reason why types with *exact* width are optional. That being said, that are present on all common architectures.

---

References: Drafts n1256 for C99 and n1570 for C11 give minimal sizes that an implementation can replace with greater values in 5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types

> The values given below shall be replaced by constant expressions suitable for use in #if
>   preprocessing directives. Moreover, except for CHAR_BIT and MB_LEN_MAX, the
>   following shall be replaced by expressions that have the same type as would an
>   expression that is an object of the corresponding type converted according to the integer
>   promotions. Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude
>   (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.
>
> - number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte)
>     CHAR_BIT 8
>
> ...
>
> - maximum value for an object of type unsigned short int
>     USHRT_MAX 65535 // 2<sup>16</sup> - 1
>
> ...
>
> - maximum value for an object of type unsigned int
>     UINT_MAX 65535 // 2<sup>16</sup> - 1
>
> ...
>
> - maximum value for an object of type unsigned long int
>     ULONG_MAX 4294967295 // 2<sup>32</sup> - 1
>
> ...
>
> - maximum value for an object of type unsigned long long int
>     ULLONG_MAX 18446744073709551615 // 2<sup>64</sup> - 1

Answer (score 3):

A variable can have different size depending on the hardware.

On microcontrolers and older processors there were 8bit and 16bit architectures ( a common PC nowadays has more or less 64bit architecture and the standard was 32 bit a few years ago). These have "smaller" variables then what someone would expect when coming from Java or a modern PC.

For example an `int` could only be 16bit. This could lead to problems if the code is ported from a system that expects it to be 32bit, because it can result in integer overflow.

To remedy this new types were declared that have a system independent implementation.

`int32_t` is always 32bit. Internally it might map to an (for example) `int` or a `long int` depending what the implementation details are.

With these types the programmer can be sure that he always gets a variable large enough for the operation.